# Simultaneous write and read to/from a FIFO

Tags: fifo, microsemi-fpga

Could someone, please, clarify whether or not I could simultaneously read and write from the soft FIFO described in [this](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/130821-smartgen-cores-reference-guide-for-libero-soc) document on p.157? It does say that I can use separate read and write clocks. I assume, this feature is rather for being able to read and write with different clock rates. But how about read and writes simultaneously? Is it even a common practice to have simultaneous r/w access to FIFOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any FIFO can be simultaneously read from and written to. Reads are valid only if the FIFO is not empty, and writes are valid only if the FIFO is not full. Most implementations also have optional element count outputs that allow flow control actions before critical states are reached.

There is an option to use separate clocks if you want to use the FIFO for clock domain crossing, but if both sides use the same clock, this option should be disabled as it increases resource usage and delay (in cycles) between input and output.

Comment: This is what I want to hear! Should I assume that this applies to the FIFO referenced in the document?

Comment: @Nazar, I'd expect it to be documented if it didn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is common practice to use FIFOs to move data across clock domains.  It is also common practice for FIFOs to allow reading and writing at the same time.